# Syntax error: OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

I am trying to build a SQL Database Project, which was created in Visual Studio, in Azure DevOps build pipeline. However, when I build the database project, I get the following error:

> Error SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY

I am currently exporting script from SSMS 18, and importing them into my Visual Studio project. The current 'Target Platform' is set to '**Azure SQL Database**'.

Note: The script which has the OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY is part of my CREATE script as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [Table1](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [VALUE1] [bigint] NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(

    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Table1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Table2FK] FOREIGN KEY([Table2FKID])
REFERENCES [Table2])
GO
```

Also, the following is the compatibility level as shown in SSMS:

[image]

I would really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: What compatibility level is your Azure SQL Database in? By default they are in 140, which does not support that syntax (as it was introduced in SQL Server 2019).

Comment: @Larnu it is SQL Server 2019 (150)

Comment: Post the full statement you are using then, not a snippet. Also, if it's SQL Server 2019 why say in the question you are using Azure SQL Database? Azure SQL Database and SQL Server 2019 are not the same. What version of SQL Server are you *really* using? What is the output of `PRINT @@VERSION` and `SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE [name] = DB_NAME();`? Update your question and tags to reflect that.

Comment: @Larnu when using the PRINT script, I get the following: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8... and when I use the SELECT script provided, I get back 150. I was referring to the Target in VS on the DB project is set to Azure SQL. However I looked at the properties of the DB, the compatibility value said 'SQL Server 2019 (150)'.

Comment: *"I get the following: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8"* Then you *aren't* using SQL Server 2019; you're using Azure SQL Database. What about the script?

Comment: @Larnu I have the following after as part on my CREATE statement: 

 [Table1ID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Table1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Table2FK] FOREIGN KEY([Table2FKID])
REFERENCES [Table2])
GO

Comment: Don't put that in the comments... Use the [edit] feature. That statement doesn't look valid to me though. `[Table1ID] ASC )` is not a valid start of a statement.

Comment: @sqlenthusiast, in addition to setting the target platform to Azure SQL Database, make sure the miscellaneous database settings in the project is SQL Server 2019 (150) compatibility level.

Comment: @Larnu I made the edit. I am able to build the code successfully in VS - sorry this is new to me.

Comment: @sqlenthusiast, note that the [OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/behind-the-scenes-on-optimize-for-sequential-key/ba-p/806888) option should not be used routinely even if the key is incremental.

Comment: @DanGuzman I have added a screenshot in my post about the compatibility level. Based on the above, would it be fine to remove the OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY part?

Comment: @sqlenthusiast, the create table statement in your question is invalid because the Table1ID column specified for the primary key constraint does not exist in the table. Same with the FK. If those problems is corrected, I would expect your project to build successfully. But I suggest you read the link I provided  before using the option.

Comment: @DanGuzman sorry typo on my end. The script runs successfully in SSMS and the build is successful in VS. It's just Azure DevOps which is throwing the error. Will have a read through the link provided. Thanks.

Comment: Are you building project in the Azure DevOps pipeline using the same source as the successful local VS build? Not sure if it will provide more insight for an answer but consider adding the build pipeline yaml to your question,

Comment: @JasonPan thank you for the comment. This seemed to be the only solution I could find as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete `, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF`, will solve the issue.

The reason for this problem is that your local generated sql script is generated in accordance with the latest sql server 2019, and the version of sql server used in devops may be inconsistent, causing the error to occur.

The script I generated on sql server2019 before, run it in sql server2008, and the error occurred is the same as yours.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this issue with SQL Server 2019 Merge Replication snapshot scripts. Setting the database compatibility level down to 2017 and that fixed the snapshot scripts by removing the "OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF" option. Our subscribers were 2017. So, I would think you will have the same results without the effort and time of removing the option manually.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).